# Save txt-file in Java with the right charset to get the €-sign

Tags: java, character-encoding, text-files, symbols

I want so save a java generated txt-file. I do it this way:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      builder.append(Satz[i][j]+"");
      if(j < col - 1)
         builder.append(";");
   }
   builder.append("\n");
}
System.out.println("builder");
System.out.println(builder);
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
    //writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        writer.write(builder.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried the version which is commented out (`OutputStreamWriter`) but that didn't worked too.

So the problem is, the code `System.out.println(builder);` gives me the string how ist looks like, before saving the txt-file. Here it looks like this:

```
von 24,5 mio€ (vorjahr: bereinigt 11,4 mio€)
```

In the txt-file, it looks like this:

```
24,5 mioâ‚¬ (vorjahr: bereinigt 11,4 mioâ‚¬)
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me with this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is actually **in** the file, on the byte level, as opposed to what it **looks** like?  The latter is under the control of whatever is displaying the content - and in particular, is it aware that the content is UTF-8-encoded?

Comment: There can be many different config errors resulting in the problem you describe. So a few questions helping in the analysis: What's the tool (notepad / editor / whatsoever) you're using when looking into the text file? What's your Java platform default encoding (`System.getProperty("file.encoding")`)? Is `"€".length()==1`?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the writer stores your strings in `UTF-8` format. When you open the stored text file with a text editor (such as Notepad++) that is set to `UTF-8`, you should see the same string. Note that even though special characters look wrong when viewing the text file in another format, the data in the file is still correct and can be read by your application to reobtain the stored string.

Answer (score 0):

From the characters you see, the most probable setting is:

Your Java editor and compiler are set up to use a consistent encoding, probably (but not necessarily) UTF-8.

When you run your Java program, the default encoding seems to be UTF-8. You can check it with `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`, and you get a file that encodes its characters according to the UTF-8 rules, where the Euro sign results in three bytes `E2 82 AC`.

When you view the file, you use an editor that assumes Windows CP-1252 encoding (maybe the standard Windows Editor app NOTEPAD.EXE?). In CP-1252, every character occupies exactly one byte. The editor then treats the three bytes `E2 82 AC` (meant to represent the Euro sign) as instead being three single characters `â‚¬`.

Who is going to read the file?

- If it's a Java program similar to yours, you can safely ignore the fact that some Windows editor shows nonsense (or you can open the file from the editor and specify the UTF-8 encoding, e.g. in the open dialog).
- If it's the Windows Editor on a typical machine in Western Europe, it'll assume CP1252 encoding. So you should write your file specifically in that encoding:

  ```
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), "CP1252"));
  ```

Anyway, your program generating the file and the application to later read the file should first agree on a common character encoding (be it CP1252, UTF-8 or whatever). Otherwise, you'll see nonsense results like above.